# i write this code to delete a row in but it returning terminating app due uncaught

Tags: ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    animalArray  = @[@"dog",@"cat",@"lion",@"tiger"];

    placeArray = @[@"india",@"goa"];

    bugArray = @[@"tauseef",@"tauseef"];

    [sectionArray addObject:animalArray];
    [sectionArray addObject:placeArray];
    [sectionArray addObject:bugArray];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [animalArray count];
            break;
         case 1:
            return [placeArray count];
        default:
            return [bugArray count];
            break;
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sectionArray.count;
}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Animal";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"Place";
            break;
        default:
            return @"Bugs";
            break;
    }
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"taskTableViewCell";

    taskTableViewCell *cell = (taskTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"taskTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    self.customeCell = cell;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [animalArray    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [placeArray     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = [bugArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
        [sectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight ];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: please format that code properly, include further information regarding the error, what the full error message is and at what line it occurs. In general you should include some text in the body of the question, not only in the title.

Comment: Please ask a question in addition to posting code.

Answer (score 1):

Im am guessing that the actual error you get is an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, because your `[sectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` is wrong.

You have to delete from the actual arrays that hold the data, not delete an entire section.

```
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        [animalArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
     case 1:
        [placeArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    default:
        [bugArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
}
```

What your code actual does is remove a row from the tableView and remove a section from the sectionArray. That will cause `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to return a section count of 2 instead of the previous 3. And your tableView will requery the number of rows and will expect the count to be decreased by one because you tell it that you delete some, which will conflict with the returned count (the same as before).

Comment: By this code both row ans section are deleating.. but i want to delete a selected row....

Comment: @ErMohdTauseef No, this code only deletes a single row.